# How to use scrapy-jsonrpc with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-services, scrapy

I need **scrapy-jsonrpc** to monitor my spiders. I have added parameters in settings.py in my Scrapy project,

```
JSONRPC_ENABLED=True 
JSONRPC_LOGFILE=None 
JSONRPC_PORT=[6080, 7030] 
JSONRPC_HOST='127.0.0.1'
```

but when I point to `http://localhost:6080/crawler`, it does not work. It seems the web service does not work, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Scrapy 1.0+.

Current docs on [`scrapy-jsonrpc`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-jsonrpc) are incomplete. They're missing installation instructions.

In Scrapy 1.0, the webservice was removed from the built-in extensions so you need to enable it in your settings.

Make sure you:

- install scrapy-jsonrpc (e.g. `pip install scrapy-jsonrpc`)
- have the extension declared,

e.g.

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy_jsonrpc.webservice.WebService': 500,
}
```

- `JSONRPC_ENABLED=True`
- the rest of your settings for scrapy-jsonrpc (thos in your question look fine)